# Do I have to use try/except every time I call a function?

Tags: python, try-except

Running the code below, after calling the first function with the string parameter, the program terminates. That is obvious. But, what do I have to do in order to get the second function call considered?

```
def sum_digits_number(number):
    sum = 0
    for digit in str(number):
        sum += int(digit)

    print(sum)


while True:
    try:
        sum_digits_number("ciao")
        sum_digits_number(9)
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a valid argument")
        break
```

Comment: generally have better control on what data types enter your functions in the first place

Comment: Are you understanding try/catch block correctly? Give it a read: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Handle the error inside the function instead of outside. This will do what you have asked in your question, but it might not always be a good idea.

Comment: That's what I thought in the first place, but I've never used try/catch block and not even python, so I'll give it a try!

Comment: You explicitly *tell* the program to a) not run ``sum_digits_number(9)`` if ``sum_digits_number("ciao")`` fails, and b) terminate if either call fails. *Don't do that* if you don't want to terminate the program and run ``sum_digits_number``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Remove `while True` loop (it does not make sense here)
- Place `try/except` inside `sum_digits_number` method

Code:

```
def sum_digits_number(number):
    try:
        s = 0
        for digit in str(number):
            s += int(digit)
        print(s)
    except ValueError:
        print('Not a valid argument')


sum_digits_number('ciao')
sum_digits_number(9)
```

Output:

```
Not a valid argument
9
```

Comment: Oh ok, I did not think that for sure. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the title question is no, not every function needs to be wrapped in a `try`. Only functions you expect to throw, and want to handle need to be wrapped.

Having said that, here, yes, both function calls will need to be wrapped individually. Once one throws, the `except` will be entered and the second call will be skipped. This doesn't mean however that you need two (or more) fully written `try`s in this code. You could put the string arguments in a list, loop over that list, and inside the loop have a `try`:

```
for arg in ["ciao", 9]:
    try:
        sum_digits_number(arg)
    except ValueError:
        # Handle individual failure however here
```

You could also extract the `try` out into its own function if it becomes complex, or, have the `try` inside of `sum_digits_number` and handle failure internally. Which you use though depends on specifics of the particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of try/excepting outside the function just check the type in the function:

```
def sum_digits_number(number):
    if not isinstance(number, int):
        print("Not a valid argument")
    else:
        print(sum(map(int, str(number))))

sum_digits_number("ciao")
sum_digits_number(9)
```

Or use 2 try/except blocks. One for each function call

Comment: I just gave it an up vote, this looks much cleaner.